# For garbage collection, what's the difference between unreachable and uncollectable?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I'm debugging an issue, where our program suddenly stalls for multiple seconds. As part of the debugging, I've turned on Python's garbage collector debugging:

```
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_STATS)
```

While running our code, I get the following output:

```
gc: collecting generation 0...
gc: objects in each generation: 1020 166 77161
gc: done, 913 unreachable, 0 uncollectable, 0.0004s elapsed
```

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html), I can't find what the difference is between unreachable and uncollectable. Can someone explain the difference in plain language and with a Python code example of how an  object becomes either unreachable or uncollectable?

Comment: Do you understand how garbage collection works in the first place? Did you try searching for the words `unreachable` and `uncollectable` in that documentation, and reading the surrounding text? I don't really know how to make it any simpler than what it already says, unless it helps to explain the theory.

Comment: @KarL; FWIW, I don't think the documentation explains the difference between them.

Comment: `gc.garbage` is described as `A list of objects which the collector found to be unreachable but could not be freed (uncollectable objects).` Seems clear enough to me: the uncollectable ones are a subset that couldn't be freed. It's also clear enough from the ordinary meaning of the word: the ones that could not be collected.

Comment: Yes, I read that part and I've read various websites about garbage collection, but it's still not very clear to me. I think someone explaining it in plain language e.g. why something becomes uncollectable with a simple code example would be very enlightening to me and many others.